# split up data frame into chunks and then apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lapply

I have a (big)dataset which looks like this:-

```
dat <- data.frame(m=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",3),rep("c",2)),
          n1 =round(rnorm(mean = 20,sd = 10,n = 9)))

g <- rnorm(20,10,5)


dat
  m     n1
1 a 15.132
2 a 17.723
3 a  3.958
4 a 19.239
5 b 11.417
6 b 12.583
7 b 32.946
8 c 11.970
9 c 26.447
```

I want to perform a t-test on each category of "m" with vector`g` like

```
n1.a <- c(15.132,17.723,3.958,19.329)
```

I need to do a t-test like `t.test(n1.a,g)`

I initially thought about breaking them up into list using `split(dat,dat$m)` and
then use `lapply`, but it is not working .

Any thoughts on how to go about it ?

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: each element of the list is a dataframe like list , from which i cannot extract the "n1" values

Comment: `rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 4:2)`

Comment: You want to test that `n1` is 0, say, for each `m` (a one sample t test)? Or A two sample t-test for each pair of `m`s?

Comment: Do you want to perform a t.test for *each* couple of categories `m`? Like, a-b, a-c, b-c?

Comment: @Edward , t-test with a separate vector

Comment: Is `lapply(split(dat, dat$m), function(x) t.test(x$n1))` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do

```
lapply(split(dat, dat$m), function(x) t.test(x$n1, g))
```

Output

```
$a

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x$n1 and g
t = 1.9586, df = 3.2603, p-value = 0.1377
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.033451 27.819258
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  21.0000   10.1071 


$b

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x$n1 and g
t = 2.3583, df = 2.3202, p-value = 0.1249
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.96768 25.75349
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  20.0000   10.1071 


$c

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x$n1 and g
t = 13.32, df = 15.64, p-value = 6.006e-10
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 13.77913 19.00667
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  26.5000   10.1071
```

Data

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(m=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",3),rep("c",2)),
          n1 =round(rnorm(mean = 20,sd = 10,n = 9)))
g <- rnorm(20,10,5)
```

Comment: It  is working for the t test , but not working when i substitute it with  a custom function .`f.t <- function(x){
  z <- t.test(x,g)$p.value
  return(z)
}`

Comment: If you need to get only the p-values, you can use `lapply(split(dat, dat$m), function(x) t.test(x$n1, g)$p.value)`

Comment: `tapply(dat$n1, dat$m, FUN=t.test, y=g)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution using `map` from `purrr`:

```
dat %>% 
  split(.$m) %>% 
  map(~ t.test(.x$n1, g), data = .x$n1)
```

Or, using `lapply` as you mentioned, which will store all of your t-test statistics in a list (or a shorter version using `by`, thanks @markus):

```
dat <- split(dat, dat$m)
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) t.test(x$n1, g))
```

Or

```
dat <- by(dat, m, function(x) t.test(x$n1, g))
```

Which gives us:

```
  $a

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  .x$n1 and g
t = 1.5268, df = 3.0809, p-value = 0.2219
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.61161  33.64902
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  21.2500   10.2313 


$b

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  .x$n1 and g
t = 1.8757, df = 2.2289, p-value = 0.1883
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -7.325666 20.863073
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  17.0000   10.2313 


$c

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  .x$n1 and g
t = 10.565, df = 19, p-value = 2.155e-09
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  7.031598 10.505808
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  19.0000   10.2313
```

Comment: Your second option a bit shorter: `by(dat, m, function(x) t.test(x$n1))`